# Como deixar um option selecionado

Tags: jquery, html

Como faço para deixar selecionado um `option` via **jquery**? Sei que é pelo seu atributo `selected`, mas não tenho idéia de como fazer isto.

O código a seguir para exemplificar como eu estava fazendo:

**Sessão**

```
 var sessao = localStorage.getItem('selected');
 var nomeSessao = localStorage.getItem('selectedName');
            if((sessao*1) >0)
            {
                    $('.optSelecionado').text(nomeSessao);
            }
```

**Listagem do option**

```
function mapa()
{              $.unblockUI();
                var identificador = localStorage.getItem('identificador');
                var sessao     = localStorage.getItem('selected');
                var nomeSessao = localStorage.getItem('selectedName');
                $('.optSelecionado').text(nomeSessao);
                var url = urlprojeto+"/dispositivo/service/enterprise/apps/mapa.php";
                var www = "device="+identificador+"";
                var www = get_contents(url,www);
                var wwwD  = www.dados;
                var wwwLen  = wwwD.length;
                var ts = '<select id="caminho" style="width: 100%;">';
                    ts+= '<option class="optSelecionado" value=""></option>';
                for( s=0; s<wwwLen; s++ )
                {
                    var referencia = wwwD[s].erp_obr_ass_codigo;
                    var nome       = wwwD[s].erp_obr_ass_nome;
                    var identacao  = wwwD[s].identacao;
                    ts+= '<option value="'+referencia+'" name="'+identacao+'">'+identacao+'</option>';
                }
                ts+='</select>';
                $(".mapa").html(ts);
}
```

Porém usando o `text` ele duplica minha opção, gostaria de deixar um `option` sem nada, tentei usando a função `remove()` para retirar a classe `optSelecionado`, mas como disse gostaria de tem um `option` em branco

Comment: Vai deixar ele selecionado pelo value ou text ? qual seria a condição para marca-lo como selected?

Comment: seria a seguinte situação, tenho uma "sessão" se ele estiver nesta sessão (que é feita pelo value do próprio option) gostaria que mesmo já viesse com o value desta sessão.

Comment: Poste algum código que exemplifique isso por favor.

Comment: editei a pergunta da uma olhada

Comment: Postei uma solução antes de você editar a pergunta, agora com sua edição entendi menos ainda oque você quer, você quer deixar o input vazio com a class `optSelecionado` selecionado?

Comment: @FelipeAssunção a sua solução me atende

Comment: eu apenas tentei exemplificar o que eu quero fazer, mas é algo simples, que com o `.prop()` me atende

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seguem alguns exemplos de como selecionar um option:

```js
// Selecionando o ultimo.
$("option:last").prop('selected', 'true')
  // Selecionando o primeiro.
$("option:first").prop('selected', 'true')
  // Selecionando pelo value
$("option[value=audi]").prop('selected', 'true')
  // Selecionando pelo texto
$("option:contains('Car Builder')").prop('selected', 'true')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select>
  <option value="saab">Saab Motors</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel Cars</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi Car Builder</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo Motorcycles</option>
</select>
```